# Will the "official" moderators of area51 proposals become moderators on this meta too?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-exchange, moderation

So far every single moderator of a non-beta stack exchange website became a moderator on meta too. I never agreed with this; besides the fact that we have enough moderators already I don't see what's the point of giving them the mod status here too.

I think meta.stackoverflow.com should have its own moderators: the most active and helpful users here on meta, who are not also moderators elsewhere. But that's besides the point.

What I want to ask is: Will the community elected moderators of stack exchange websites (cooking for example) become moderators here on meta too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The moderators of the Stack Exchange sites are only moderators in their own site domain (i.e. sitename.stackexchange.com and meta.sitename.stackexchange.com).

Comment: meta.SO is particular, in transition to separate into meta.SE and a meta.SO, only for SO. So in the future, SO mods will probably be the only ones on meta.SO, but what about meta.SE, then? Particular moderators, the team only, or again a mix of every SE site?